# Extracting type of object properties using generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have this following code

```
type GTMCreator<Payload> = (payload: Payload) => "a";

interface BudgetPayload {
  a: 2;
}
interface MarketPayload {
  b: 2;
}

interface Events {
  budget: GTMCreator<BudgetPayload>;
  market: GTMCreator<MarketPayload>;
}

const budget: GTMCreator<BudgetPayload> = (payload) => "a";
const market: GTMCreator<MarketPayload> = () => "a";

const events: Events = {
  budget,
  market
};

type Push = <T extends keyof typeof events>(
  event: T,
  ...payload: Parameters<typeof events[T]>
) => void;

const something = () => ({ push: (items: any) => "s" });

const push: Push = (event, payload) => {
  something().push(events[event](payload));
};
```

I expected the typeof payload to be inferred based on the event name passed as the first parameter. It is now inferring as

> Type 'BudgetPayload | MarketPayload' is not assignable to type
> 'BudgetPayload & MarketPayload'.

Why is it not inferred as 'BudgetPayload | MarketPayload' ?

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-poitras-0d8qh?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: See if [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-gates-j13sm) helps

Comment: `event` and `payload` as unspecified generic types end up looking like two uncorrelated union-typed values to the compiler.  You know they are correlated and that `event` and `payload` should match up, but the compiler does not realize this.   See the answer to the question this duplicates for possible ways to proceed.

Comment: Like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/ymA8QN)